# UIWebView or UIScrollView for HTML like View in iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Sorry for this simple question but I am looking for the design pattern for adding a simple HTML like page to an iPhone app.

My intuition tells me that making a View with a full screen WebView inside is obviously the easiest option, but I think a UIScrollView is better.

What's the best practice?

I basically want to have some text, float some images, add a few links etc.

Should I use WebView or ScrollView?

Thank you,

Kent

Answer (score 2):

Well you're going to need a `UIWebView` if you want to display the contents of a local or remote web page. You would want to use a `UIScrollView` if you wanted to draw all of the content programmatically.

I think you want a `UIWebView`.